# How to schedule my stored procedure to run when there is an update in data in SQL without using the sql server agent?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering whether is it possible to schedule my stored procedure to run without using the SQL Server Agent (as I don't have access), I would like it to run when there is new data ingested (I have an upload date column in the data, not sure can we use that to make the update when there is a change in date from the previous data).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It allows you to execute custom code when data is changed (an after trigger) or instead CURD operations (instead trigger).

In your case, you my need `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` trigger as you need to apply logic when data is modified.

Comment: how would i need to write the code ? do you have an example i can follow ? im not familiar with the codes yet sorry

Comment: Could you show me what's the code you need to execute after data is modified or explain the table design?

Comment: [dbo.tbl_masterdata] – if data updates here then run the stored procedure ,[archive.dbo_masterdata] – update the new master data into here .
The table is the same as [dbo.tbl_masterdata] the just to duplicate it to [archive.dbo_masterdata]

Comment: code:
INSERT INTO [archive.dbo_masterdata]
SELECT *
,cast(getdate() AS DATE) as ARCHIVE_DATE
FROM [dbo.tbl_masterdata]

Comment: @DanielKoh So you just need a log table, right? Could you share the version of your SQL Server?

Comment: i wont be able to as its company data :/ sorry maybe you can explain the significant part of the code ?

Comment: @DanielKoh OK, but are you just interested in logging the data changes?